# Task Scheduler truncating PowerShell output at 80 Characters

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, truncation

No matter the formatting or output method I am trying I am not able to get around task schedulers ability to truncate output at it's default column 80 UGH

I had tried

```
Get-CimInstance  -computerName $glfServers -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Sort-Object csName | Format-Table -Property $csName, $serverStatus, $totalVisibleMemorySize, $freePhysicalMemory, $memoryUsage, $freeSpaceInPagingFiles, $lastBootTime  | Out-String -Width 120 | Out-File  'C:\Scripts\OutputFiles\ServerMemory\PyhsMem.txt'
```

I had tried `Tee-object` mostly so I could get output to both console and file only to discover that the task scheduler output would be different.

I tried all the usual suspects `Format-Table -Autosize` and `Out-file` and after days of searching I finally found the answer buried in another stackoverflow post.

I am going to post my resolution because it was a frustrating few days with no relief in sight. I just get to add this to one more thing I dislike about Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! I finally found the answer I was very close you need to use `-Stream` to get around the truncation. So the final working code block looks like this:

```
Get-CimInstance -computerName $glfServers -Class Win32_OperatingSystem |
Sort-Object csName |
Format-Table -Property $csName, $serverStatus, $totalVisibleMemorySize, $freePhysicalMemory, $memoryUsage, $freeSpaceInPagingFiles, $lastBootTime |
Out-String -Stream -Width 120 |
Out-File 'C:\Scripts\OutputFiles\ServerMemory\PyhsMem.txt'
```